# Is it better to reuse the same fetch function multiple times to get data?

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

Fairly straight-forward question, pretty new to the Fetch API and async/await. I was wondering if its better to use fetch every time I wanna get data from a file or url, or if its better to make one asynchronous fetch function that I can use multiple times as shown below

```
    async function show(url){
     try{
     let response = await fetch(url);
     if(!response.ok)
        throw new Error("Something went wrong");
     return await response.json();
    } catch(err){
        alert(err);
    }
}

show("users.json").then(data => console.log(data));
show("someFile.json").then(data => console.log(data));
```

PS: I'm new to stackoverflow so I'm sorry if I haven't asked the question right :P

Comment: If you have to use the same code in multiple places, write a function then call it. It's a general rule not only for fetching data but also for other operations :)

Comment: No I get that, I was wondering if while dealing with promises it might be a little different :P Still wrapping my head around asynchronous coding, but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never write duplicate code. So, yes, writing a function/method that encapsulates the asynchronous fetch is generally the best/recommended way.